# Disable the admin bar / probleme with responsive menu

Tags: admin-bar, responsive

I am using a plugin called

> Disable WP Admin Bar Removal

The goal : Disable the admin bar (back and frontend).

I really want to disable this bar for the dashboard but if I want to use the dashboard on my phone or tablet, the left responsive menu disapeared. The button of the responsive menu is in the admin bar, that's the problem. Is there a way to change that ?

Comment: You should contact the plugin author as this is a issue caused by the plugin

Comment: Yes but all that kind of plugins does the same thing

Comment: Please link to the plugin. Note that toolbar is no longer considered "optional" in admin, so removing it there is "crazy hacks" realm. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack and a half, but it does achieve the desired effect.

What this code does is add inline css to the header in admin pages, over 780px width the admin bar is hidden, under that and its shown. So you in effect hide it on desktop and show it on mobile.

Add this to your functions.php file.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_admin_bar');
function hide_admin_bar() {
     echo '<style>
          @media all and (min-width:780px) {
               #wpadminbar {
                display:none;
           } 
               html.wp-toolbar {
                padding-top:0px;
               }
          } 
      </style>';
}
```